# Percentage sharing for N number of users

Tags: mysql, database, performance, relationship

I have table like following

```
Id UserName PercentSharing ParentId
1  one      20             0
2  two      80             1
3  three    40             2
4  four     50             2
5  five     20             3
6  six      30             3
```

I want to calculate that all level should not exceed above 100%

If I change PercentSharing for Id 2 as 70 it's parent should be updated to 30 and If any percent sharing users Id 3 or 4 to any other values then it should maintain percent sharing to 100% for all parent users. e.g. user Ids 3,2,1 total should not exceed beyond 100%

I want to maintain 100% ratio for N number or level.

Please suggest do I need to change table structure?

Comment: This is not a problem of DB structure, but a problem of login used to manipulate data. I don't know if you need this kind of structure for other reasons

Comment: It is kind of problem with percent sharing store in db and calculation. I need help on this how to store this kind of data in db with N level of relationship.

Comment: There are no levels here

Comment: Compute the percent-sharing on the fly; don't pre-compute.  That is, store a "weighting", not the ultimate "pct".

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following; a nested model...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id CHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,pct INT NOT NULL
,lft INT NOT NULL
,rgt INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('A',20,1,12),
('B',80,2,11),
('C',40,3, 8),
('D',50,9,10),
('E',20,4, 5),
('F',30,6, 7); 

SELECT * FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.lft <= x.lft WHERE x.id = 'E';
+----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+
| id | pct | lft | rgt | id | pct | lft | rgt |
+----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+
| E  |  20 |   4 |   5 | A  |  20 |   1 |  12 |
| E  |  20 |   4 |   5 | B  |  80 |   2 |  11 |
| E  |  20 |   4 |   5 | C  |  40 |   3 |   8 |
| E  |  20 |   4 |   5 | E  |  20 |   4 |   5 |
+----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+

SELECT x.*, SUM(y.pct) total FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.lft <= x.lft WHERE x.id = 'E' GROUP BY x.id;
+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| id | pct | lft | rgt | total |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| E  |  20 |   4 |   5 |   160 |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```